# How to Set icon(image) in DialogBox While Click in Button Event

Tags: java, android, button

I created a Button,While i Click that Button a new Dialog Box is Displayed.In that dialog Box i have set icon and text.text is Displayed but icon(image) is not displayed in dialog Box.
Here my Coding

```
Button btnteam_westernbulldogs=new Button(this);
    btnteam_westernbulldogs.setId(team_westernbulldogsid);
    btnteam_westernbulldogs.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.team_westernbulldogs);
          public void onClick(View v){  

              createbtnteam_westernbulldogs();
          }
  });


public void createbtnteam_westernbulldogs()
{
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.team_westernbulldogs);
    alertDialog.setMessage("What kind of Banner do you Want to Create?");
    alertDialog.setButton("Text", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
           createText();

       }
    alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
    alertDialog.show();
        }     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void createbtnteam_westernbulldogs()
{
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.team_westernbulldogs);
alertDialog.setTitle("What kind of Banner do you Want to Create?");
alertDialog.setButton("Text", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
       createText();

   }
alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
alertDialog.show();
}     });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
   Try this..  

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
     builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?") 
    .setIcon(R.drawable.icon)       
    .setCancelable(false)       
    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
    {           
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
      {                
         MyActivity.this.finish();           
   }       
       })       
       .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
        {           
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
            {                
             dialog.cancel();           
            }       
          });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
```

Answer (score 0):

You must call **setTitle** with non-empty string!
Icon is displayed only if there's also title.